# SQL Server Stored procedure aborting when called from php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have spent hours trying to get to the bottom of this and it is driving me la la.

I have a simple stored procedure that just inputs 10,000 rows into a table.  This is done because it takes long enough to prove the point (about 12 seconds).

```
create table lala (id int not null identity(1,1), txt varchar(100))
go
CREATE PROCEDURE lalatest
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x int;
    SET @x = 10000;
    WHILE @x > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO lala (txt) VALUES ('blah ' + CAST(@x AS varchar(10)));
        SET @x = @x - 1;
    END;
END;
```

When I run the stored procedure from within SQL Server Management Studio, 10,000 rows are inserted into the table.

When I run it from php it just aborts after about 150 rows (the number of rows varies, suggesting a timeout issue) with no error messages or any indication that it has finished early

The `remote query timeout` setting is set to the default of 600 seconds, so its not that.

The php:

```
$sql = "exec lalatest";
sqlsrv_query($cn, $sql);
```

I have tried specifying a timeout value (which should be indefinite by default anyway) on the sqlsrv_query line and it made no difference.

I'm using php 5.6.7

and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
    Oct 20 2015 15:36:27 
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

I have all errors and warnings turned on

Anyone got any ideas as to what I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you believe it, I have made it work.  I added `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first line in the stored procedure and now it works from php as well.

Looks like having the rows affected info throws the php sqlsrv driver a wobbly.  Strange how it only does it after a certain time (about a second), perhaps something to do with when the message buffer is flushed or something.  Yes, I'm guessing, but this has solved the problem, so I'm happy.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE lalatest
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; -- must be added so that it will run from php

    DECLARE @x int;
    SET @x = 10000;
    WHILE @x > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO lala (txt) VALUES ('blah ' + CAST(@x AS varchar(10)));
        SET @x = @x - 1;
    END;
END;
```